# Command for finding users who are not logged in

Tags: shell-script, users

Is there any command that can find the number of users that are not logged into the system ?

I am trying to write a shell script that counts the number of users who are logged in and number of users that are not logged in.

Answer (score 4):

#### Listing out groups of users

You can get a list of all your local users with this command:

```
$ getent passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

**NOTE:** `getent` will return local users assuming you do not have `sssd` (or some similar service running which pulls LDAP users in too) and your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is restricted to files, i.e. it's not including things like NIS or NIS+. For pure local user's only you can resort to `awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd`.

A list of who's currently logged in:

```
$ who
```

A list of user's that are currently not loggd in:

```
$ grep -Fxvf <(who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u) \
    <(getent passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}')
```

This last one takes the list of users who are logged in and shows the list of all user's minus the logged in users, using `grep -vf`.

#### Getting counts

To get counts, simply take a `wc -l` on to the end of commands.

*not logged in*

```
$ grep -Fxvf <(who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u) \
    <(getent passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}') | wc -l
53
```

*logged in*

```
$ who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | wc -l
1
```

#### grep flags

```
-F, --fixed-strings
        Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, 
        any of which is to be matched.

-x, --line-regexp
        Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.

-v, --invert-match
        Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

-f FILE, --file=FILE
        Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains 
        zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
```

#### Using join instead of grep

You could also forgo using `grep` and use `join` instead, since this type of problem is more in `join`'s wheelhouse. We'll need to use `join -v 2` which means that we want to exclude matches and only show the uniques from our second argument, `getent ...`.

*join man page*

```
-a FILENUM
        also print unpairable lines from file FILENUM, where FILENUM is 
        1 or 2, corresponding to FILE1 or FILE2

-v FILENUM
        like -a FILENUM, but suppress joined output lines


$ join -v 2 <(who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u) \
    <(getent passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort) | wc -l
53
```

**NOTE:** The only caveat with using `join` is that both lists need to be sorted, so we have to add on a `| sort` to `getent ...`.

Comment: `getent` will also list entries from LDAP, etc. Do those count as local?

Comment: @muru - thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure that's true. I think that's the case only if sssd is running. In addition, by using `getent`, you need to make sure that `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is also only restricted to files, if you truly want local files. I'll add this as a  note in my A, thanks again.

Comment: @muru - yeah I used that one as an example, but I'm aware of there being others.

Comment: @muru - I also added a pure `/etc/passwd` only option to show it. I hate to add that since it's generally discouraged to work against those files directly 8-)

Comment: @muru - I find it a bit annoying that `getent` does not provide some switch for this. I searched but did not find one.

Comment: I do too. Makes it difficult to deal separately with local users.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to write a script that will store the number of users currently logged in a file and the total users in another file and do a `comm` over them.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

w | awk 'NR > 2 {print $1}' | sort > logged.txt #sorted list of logged users
awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd | sort > allusers.txt #sorted list of all users
comm -23 allusers.txt logged.txt #find lines unique to allusers.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner will work:

```
grep -Ev $(users | sed 's/ /|/g') /etc/passwd | awk -F: {'print $1'}
```

**How it works**:

The output of `users | sed 's/ /|/g'` will give you a `|` separated list of logged in users.

The `-E` option with grep will allow us to use more than one string (in OR condition) to match. The `-v` option will print out what does not match given strings/pattern. Combining -E and `-v` together will list all the lines that does not contain the pipe-separated strings from the output of `users | sed 's/ /|/g'`. At the end use `awk` to filter out only the usernames.